# Most efficient way of returning all results as well as limited/offset results in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query below that fetches all a limited result set from my table. I have however a table filter that requires all the results to be present to give a full range of options to pick from. Is there a way I can combine a query so that it fetches all the results as well as the limited/offset results?

```
"SELECT phone_deal_phone_allocations.*, 
                            phone_deal_phone_allocations.id as allocation_id,
                            phone_reseller_monthly_deals.*, 
                            phone_reseller_monthly_deals.id as deal_id, 
                            phone_variations.*,
                            phone_variations.id as variation_id, 
                            phone_colours.*, 
                            phone_colours.id as colour_id, 
                            phone_sizes.*,
                            phone_sizes.id as size_id,
                            phone_networks.*,
                            phone_networks.id as network_id 
                        FROM 
                        phone_deal_phone_allocations
                        JOIN phone_reseller_monthly_deals ON phone_reseller_monthly_deals.id=phone_deal_phone_allocations.deal_id 
                        JOIN phone_variations ON phone_variations.id=phone_deal_phone_allocations.phone_variations_id
                        JOIN phone_colours ON phone_colours.id=phone_variations.phone_colour_id
                        JOIN phone_sizes ON phone_sizes.id=phone_variations.phone_size_id
                        JOIN phone_networks ON phone_networks.id=phone_reseller_monthly_deals.phone_networks_id
                        ".$where."
                        AND phone_colours.phone_colour_name = 'Gold'
                        ORDER BY phone_sizes.phone_size_mb ASC 
                        LIMIT 0, 4"
```

Comment: Use a cte. select all union all select with limit.

Comment: Well, do you want all the results or just a subset?  If the total size of the result set sin `LIMIT` be reasonably small, maybe you could just cache it and then paginate on the UI.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].